# CakePHP - CRUD API: Error upon inserting to database CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, crud

I get the following error when attempting to POST to the API. I have followed [this](http://www.bravo-kernel.com/2015/04/how-to-build-a-cakephp-3-rest-api-in-minutes/) tutorial to the book and so I am unsure as to why insertion is not working.

```
Message: Call to member function error() on boolean
Trace:   ControllerTrait.php
```

My add function was made by bake but despite this, the error seems to occur during the saving of the entity.

```
public function add()
    {
        $author = $this->Authors->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $author = $this->Authors->patchEntity($author, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Authors->save($author)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The author has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The author could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $this->set(compact('author'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['author']);
    }
```

Comment: The error message itself is simply because the flash component hasn't been loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `add` action, just remove it -- this is exactly what the CRUD plugin does for you.

If you need to customize a CRUD action you need to `return $this->Crud->execute()` in the end, example:

```
public function add()
{
  $this->Crud->on('beforeSave', function (Event $e) {
    // Custom logic before save
  });

  // Make sure CRUD takes care of the rest
  return $this->Crud->execute();
}
```

But yes, it will work if you just remove the `add` method all together.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been struggling with this for hours